# Convert String to List of Dictionaries Python 3

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a piece of information like so:

```
[{"city": "Beverly Hills", "state": "", "postal_code": "", "address": "Some Address", "country": "USA"}, {"city": "New York", "state": "NY", "postal_code": "", "address": "P.O. BOX 52404", "country": "USA"}]
```

When I do `type()` it shows as `<class 'str'>`.

How do I get this information from a string to a list of dictionaries in Python 3?

I've tried `literal_eval` and got an error `malformed node or string:`, so I am not sure what the best way to do this is.'

**EDIT**

Here is an example that should be reproducible:

```
mydata = {'programs': '["France"]', 'ids': '[]', 'citizenships': '[]', 'nationalities': '["FR"]', 'places_of_birth': '[]', 'dates_of_birth': '["1973-03-25"]', 'addresses': '[{"state": null, "postal_code": null, "address": null, "city": null, "country": "FR"}]'}
for key,value in mydata.items():
    if type(value) is str:
        result = literal_eval(value)
        print("value 1: ", value)
        print("value type 2:", type(value))
        print("result 3: ", result)
        print("result  4: ", type(result))
        for item in result:
            print("item in result 5:", item)
            print("type of item in result 6:", type(item))
```

Here is the error:

> File "server.py", line 137, in insert_in_db
>           result = literal_eval(value)
>         File "/Users/user/anaconda3/envs/apicaller/lib/python3.5/ast.py", line 84, in literal_eval
>           return _convert(node_or_string)
>         File "/Users/user/anaconda3/envs/apicaller/lib/python3.5/ast.py", line 57, in _convert
>           return list(map(_convert, node.elts))
>         File "/Users/user/anaconda3/envs/apicaller/lib/python3.5/ast.py", line 62, in _convert
>           in zip(node.keys, node.values))
>         File "/Users/user/anaconda3/envs/apicaller/lib/python3.5/ast.py", line 61, in 
>           return dict((_convert(k), _convert(v)) for k, v
>         File "/Users/user/anaconda3/envs/apicaller/lib/python3.5/ast.py", line 83, in _convert
>           raise ValueError('malformed node or string: ' + repr(node))
>       ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Name object at 0x109baae48>

Maybe I am missing a step in between to check for null values? I seem to get the error on the eval `line 137`. I got the idea to use `ast.literal_eval` from that stack overflow comment mentioned below.

Is it more of a data issue than with the way I am handling it? I am not very familiar with Python so I am most likely missing something.

Comment: `literal_eval` works for your string.

Comment: For me, `eval`, `ast.literal_eval` and `json.loads` all work without issue, given the string you've provided.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert a String representation of a Dictionary to a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988228/convert-a-string-representation-of-a-dictionary-to-a-dictionary)

Comment: Take a look at the question above, it has the same problem as yours.

Answer (score 20):

```
import json

data = json.loads(<your_string>)
```

Comment: The user's string (if it's as shown) should work with literal_eval as well.  Whatever the problem is, it's probably not that the issue is that it's valid JSON but not valid Python.  Are you proposing that it's a null/None issue or something?

Answer (score 8):

I know i'm answering pretty late but hope it is helpful for other folks:

you can use:
 pip install pyyaml
    import yaml

```
x = '[{"city": "Beverly Hills", "state": "", "postal_code": "", "address": "Some Address", "country": "USA"}, {"city": "New York", "state": "NY", "postal_code": "", "address": "P.O. BOX 52404", "country": "USA"}]'

x = yaml.load(x)
```

Now string has been converted to list of dictionaries.

Comment: PyYAML's `yaml.load()`  is documented to be potentially unsafe. It is also not necessary to use it here, so there is no excuse for suggesting to use it.

Comment: **This worked for me to get a list of dicts from a str.**

`yaml.load` has been deprecated because it could be easily exploited (as @Anthon commented). 
Now a Loader has to be specified. For example `yaml.load(x, Loader=yaml.BaseLoader)`

Read https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml/wiki/PyYAML-yaml.load(input)-Deprecation for more information.

Answer (score 4):

You can use json module, if you your informating is of type string

```
import json

data = json.loads(<your_string>)

for element in data:
    for key, value in element.items():
        print("{}: {}".format(key, value))
```

Answer (score 1):

There is JSON encoder and decoder. You can have a look at [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) for documentation.
`json.loads(<to_be_convert_string>)`

`Python3` example and its output

```
import json
data = json.loads('["foo", {"bar":["baz", null, 1.0, 2]}]')
print(data) # ['foo', {'bar': ['baz', None, 1.0, 2]}]
print(type(data)) # <class 'list'>
print(type(data[0])) # <class 'str'>
print(type(data[1])) # <class 'dict'>
```

You can have more examples at this [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/json-loads-in-python/#:%7E:text=loads()%20method%20can%20be,JSON%20data%20into%20Python%20Dictionary.)

Answer (score 0):

That is of type list?

You should be able to set a variable to that list and it should work. However, if the data is a literal string you could do this:

```
import json
test = json.loads('[{"city": "Beverly Hills", "state": "", "postal_code": "", "address": "Some Address", "country": "USA"}, {"city": "New York", "state": "NY", "postal_code": "", "address": "P.O. BOX 52404", "country": "USA"}]')

print(type(test))
-><type 'list'>
```